# ag-grid with simple type row data

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am having a hard time setting up an `ag-grid` table in an Angular 6.0 application where the row data model is a an array of simple types (dates, numbers, strings, etc.)

The only way I can do so is to wrap the all the data into an object list (each object containing a single property) and pass it as the row data. It also means that I have to manually and systematically have to unwrap the data whenever I need to access it.

To put it differently, is there a way to define a columnDef without a field in ag-grid table and having it consider implicitly that the field data is the entire row data?

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: 'Athlete'}
    ],
    rowData: ['John', 'Oliver']
}
```

Comment: If your data is that much simple why use a third party library? just use a html table or ul/li with proper css.

Comment: I am also interested in the rendering/sorting/editing functionalities of ag-grid, so plain html is not enough in my case. Even it were read-only, I prefer to have one consistent table look and feel for a whole angular application, as I am using ag-grid in the more standard and complex ways.

Answer (score 3):

I think field is required but colId is not required (it will default to the field).
Field is what maps a column to the data set.
Here are more details about [column definitions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#columns-only).

It may be easier to edit your data before initializing the grid.
Something like this may work:

```
var data = ['John', 'Oliver'].map(name => {return {name} });
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {field:'name', headerName: 'Athlete'}
    ],
    rowData: data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can config your `columnDefs`

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            headerName: 'Athlete',
            valueGetter: (node) => node.data
        }
    ],
    rowData: ['John', 'Oliver']
}
```